# How to pin/unpin drop down menu in jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to create a button which will allow me to pin the drop down menu so it's visible permanently, and then unpin it, after clicking on it second time. jQuery toggle() doesn't work because it just hides the drop down, same as changing css display property.

Here's my jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/39ykn4vw/

html&css:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <button class="pin">
      pin
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

.pin {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}

.dropbtn {
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    min-width: 160px;
    min-height: 300px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: There's no jQuery / JavaScript in your content.

Comment: If you want to use jQuery you can check if the dropdown is visible with `$(.dropdown').is(':visible')` and add or remove a class to make element visible or not. This can be done in combination with mouseenter event on button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use additional class to detect pinned element:

```css
.pin {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}

.dropbtn {
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    min-width: 160px;
    min-height: 300px;
    z-index: 1;
}


.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content,
.dropdown-content.pinned {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <button class="pin" onClick="$(this).parent().toggleClass('pinned')">
      pin
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If not a css property then you can go through the link: http://webpop.github.io/jquery.pin/#link-three